# Put the .length before a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string

Code for Length of string to be displayed in front of actual string.

Example

```
length: 11, "This string"
```

Thank you.

Comment: "Go" in front of the string? Where? What does that mean?

Comment: Okay, so see in the example I gave how it has the number 11 in front of the string? How would I code that to make the length of the string to be in front of the string? Do you get what I'm asking?

Comment: `var str = str.length + ', ' + str;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var str = 'Hello World';
console.log('length: ' + str.length + ', "' + str + '"');
```

Evaluates to:

```
length: 11, "Hello World"
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

```
var str = "This string";
var n = str.length;
var displaystring = 'length: '+ n + ', "' + str + '"'
//display the above string however you want.
//example below to show in a control name demo
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = displaystring;
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @pointy that its not clear what you really need done but this might give you some idea

```
var str1 = "This string";
var str2 = str1.length;
var result = str2.concat(str1);
```